# Problem with special characters

Tags: babel, persian, arabtex

I have not any problem with English LaTeX but today I wanted to write in Farsi (Persian) in LaTeX. I tried to write in Arabic instead but I faced an issue. I wrote this simple code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[Arabic]{babel}

\begin{document}
می خواهد
\end{document}
```

I saw this error:

> - Local config file arabic.cfg used
> - (C:\Users\me\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\latex\arabi\arabic.cfg)))
>     (untitled-2.aux) ("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX
>     2.9\tex\latex\base\ifthen.sty" ) ! Undefined control sequence.  \farsiya 
>                      l.7 می
>          خواهد ?

However, I have not any problem when I am writing for example an Arabic word like "سلام". How can I fix this issue?

**EDIT**: I wrote the below code but again I got an error.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[LAE,LFE]{fontenc}
\usepackage[farsi,arabic]{babel}
\TOCLanguage{farsi}

\title{این یک مقاله تست است}
\author{محمد}

\begin{document}

\selectlanguage{farsi}
\maketitle
\newpage
\tableofcontents
\section{مطالعه ی عمیق}
\subsection{آری!}

می خواهد باید برویم
$$E=m c^{2}$$
\end{document}
```

The error is:

> ! LaTeX Error: Command \farsiya unavailable in encoding LAE.
>
> See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation. Type  H
>     for immediate help.  ...
>
> l.4 ...C {\meem }\IeC {\farsiya }\IeC {\qaf }}}{1}
>   ?

However, when I removed the `\tableofcontents` code, I got no error.

Comment: I'm confused, do you want to write in Farsi or Arabic? Because you said you wanted to try Farsi, but then wrote in Arabic.

Comment: please try with `\usepackage[farsi]{babel}`

Comment: @touhami I got this error:
! LaTeX Error: Encoding scheme `LAE' unknown.

Comment: @Alenanno I want to write in Farsi but I haven't found any Farsi packages for LaTeX so I tried to write in Arabic.

Comment: @KNP Should [this be correct output](http://i.stack.imgur.com/yyp31.png) using what you wrote?

Comment: @Alenanno yes it should be the output but I haven't get this. I got only error.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A sample of arabic, farsi document with arabi package

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[LAE,LFE]{fontenc}
\usepackage[farsi,arabic]{babel}
\begin{document}
 سلام
\selectlanguage{farsi}
می خواهد
\end{document}
```

if you want farsi to be the main language

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[LAE,LFE]{fontenc}
\usepackage[farsi,arabic]{babel}
\TOCLanguage{farsi}
\begin{document}
\selectlanguage{farsi}
می خواهد
\end{document}
```

---

**Update** From arabi user-guide

> **Important note.**
>
> Nevertheless, since the Arabic part of the code was
>   developed first and the Farsi part was developed after, we advise the
>   user who wants to mix the two languages to call the option `arabic`
>   always after `farsi`. And if you want Farsi to be the main document
>   language, just issue the command
>
> ```
>               \TOCLanguage{english} *
> ```
>
> and call the Farsi language whenever needed as
>   shown below. This may save you a lot of trouble (concerning the choice
>   of the fonts to be used by the system) until the system becomes more
>   mature.

`*` I think the package's author means `\TOCLanguage{farsi}`

---

If one don't need arabic the solution is to use

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[LAE,LFE]{fontenc}
\usepackage[farsi]{babel}
\TOCLanguage{farsi}


\title{این یک مقاله تست است}
\author{محمد}

\begin{document}
\maketitle
\newpage
\tableofcontents
\section{مطالعه ی عمیق}
\subsection{آری!}

می خواهد باید برویم
$$E=m c^{2}$$

\end{document}
```

If one needs both languages he can works around by

```
{\makeatletter
\let\@arabic@R\@farsi@R
\tableofcontents}
```

---

**Complet code**

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[LAE,LFE]{fontenc}
\usepackage[farsi,arabic]{babel}
\TOCLanguage{farsi}


\title{این یک مقاله تست است}
\author{محمد}

\begin{document}

\selectlanguage{farsi}
\maketitle
\newpage
{\makeatletter
\let\@arabic@R\@farsi@R
\tableofcontents}
\section{مطالعه ی عمیق}
\subsection{آری!}

می خواهد باید برویم
$$E=m c^{2}$$

\end{document}
```

Comment: I get the same error when I use \maketitle. Don't you have any idea?

Comment: may be because `\maketitle` is before `\selectlanguage{farsi}` no?

Comment: But I still have the same problem with \tableofcontents.

Comment: if you don't need to mix arabic and farsi text in your document just remove `arabic` option from `babel` and remove `\selectlanguage{farsi}` if you need both languages you can try `\usepackage[arabic,farsi]{babel}` this solves your problem but this is not what the package's doc recommend. I will give this a try.

Comment: Thank you again! :) And a question. Is it okay to put everything between `{\makeatletter
\let\@arabic@R\@farsi@R`? I did it and everything worked perfect!

Comment: I am not sure, it seems to be ok, i did try and it works without any problem but it could be problematic if there is arabic sections. any way the change is local to table of contents.

Comment: Yes. I tried too and it was okay. And another question, how can I write an English word in the context? if I write for example "Today" it would be transcribed to Persian. How can I prevent LaTeX from doing this?

Comment: you need to type `\textLR{today}`

Comment: Thanks. I faced another problem :( I dunno ask it here or add another question. I wanted to insert a photo but the photo is not at the center and it's partially outside of the page. My code is here: `\begin{figure}[!ht]
\centering
  \includegraphics{download.jpg}
  \caption{d}
  \label{fig:earth}
\end{figure}` Moreover, when I add `[width=\linewidth]` I give the FATAL error.

Comment: please ask a new question.